# Can "Automatically update e-mail addresses based on e-mail address policy" delete e-mail addresses?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email

When editing a mailbox's e-mail addresses in the Exchange 2010 Management Console I see the checkbox:

[image]

My only e-mail address policy defines email addresses like *username@mydomain.com*.  If I edit a mailbox to add an alias e-mail address that doesn't conform to this policy (such as *shipping@mydomain.com*) is there:

1. An action I might later take (such as re-apply an e-mail address policy), or
2. An event that might happen on its own (like something that would happen during an Exchange update rollup or the like)

that would **remove or otherwise delete the non-conforming e-mail alias I added to the mailbox?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't uncheck the "Automatically update e-mail addresses based on e-mail address policy" then the next time the policy takes affect it would overwrite your custom address you set IF this is the primary SMTP address you are editing.

You'll need to uncheck it on that mailbox and manually control its email addresses going forward IF it is the Primary address you are wanting to change.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is it that triggers that time when the policy next takes effect? My question stems from the fact I've added non-conforming e-mail addresses to mailboxes, *not* de-selected the checkbox, and come back to the mailbox *many* months (and maintenance cycles) later and found all the addresses intact. Yet I've also revisited mailboxes I swore I added an address to, yet no such address exists. So what can trigger the overwrite action?

Comment: It only affects the primary (set as reply) address.  So if you've added shipping@mydomain.com as a secondary address then it should be retained.  Also, the policy has a schedule it runs on (which is established when it's created or can be modified later).

Comment: OK--that's an important distinction.  To make certain I understand correctly, you're saying that I can leave the checkbox *enabled*, add any address so long as I am **not editing the default reply address**, and those additional address will not be automatically altered?

Comment: Correct.  It's been this way since Exchange 2007.  You can see here: http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/managing-email-address-policies.html -- "When a recipient has “Automatically update e-mail addresses based on email address policy” enabled, all primary e-mail addresses (default reply addresses) of e-mail address types will always be set from the e-mail address policy. This means that if you edit the primary address to be a different e-mail address, it will always revert back to the one specified in the e-mail address policy."